# Can we use the terms 'class of sets' and 'family of sets' interchangeably?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I read in pg-4, *Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis* by Simmons that *class* refers to a set of sets while *family* refers to a set of classes. I formulated an example for the same - if points are elements in a Cartesian plane; a set may refer to a circle, a class may refer to the set of all circles, and a family may refer to a set of all polygons.

Now, the confusion is can use the terms 'class of sets' and 'family of sets' interchangeably? That is, will 'class of all open sets' and 'family of all open sets' mean the same? What is the basic difference between them?

Thanks.

Comment: I think family can take on different meanings based on context -- can you show the exact definitions he gives?

Comment: @Soke is right. There is no "standard" meaning for the term "family", except that it's a collection of objects with a similar property of some sort.